# Reduce or map the object by the field names

Tags: javascript

i have an object like:

```
const obj = {
  obj2: { 
    number: 123123,
    obj3: [{
      number: 321321
    }, {
      number: 543543
    }]
  },
  obj5: { 
    number: 52343,
    obj6: [{
      number: 753456
    }, {
      number: 12312
    }]
 },
}
```

wanted output: [123123, 321321, 543543, 52343, 753456, 12312]

the ways i'm resolving it is just..
creating an array like

```
[obj2.number, obj2.obj3[0].number, obj5.number, obj5.obj6[0].number].find(el => Boolean(el))
```

and it's looks bad. Can't figuring out how to do it in function way.
Like make Object entries of this object, then reduce it and ask for field, if it's not there, go deeper etc.

or the first value in field named 'number' which is not null (boolean true)

Comment: So what is your question and what is the code you tried to achieve your goal?

Answer (score 0):

Not a fancy way and not guaranteed to work for each and every case, but you could start from here

```js
const obj = {
  obj2: { 
    number: 123123,
    obj3: [{
      number: 321321
    }, {
      number: 543543
    }]
  },
  obj5: { 
    number: 52343,
    obj6: [{
      number: 753456
    }, {
      number: 12312
    }]
 },
}

getPropValues = function(obj, name) {
 let result = [];
 
 if(Array.isArray(obj)) {
   for(let i =0;i<obj.length;++i) {
      let innerResult = getPropValues(obj[i],name);
      result = result.concat(innerResult);
   }
   return result;
 }

 if(typeof obj === 'object') {
   for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      if(key === name) {
         result.push(value);
      } else if(Array.isArray(value) || typeof value === 'object') {
         result = result.concat(getPropValues(value,name));
      }
   }
 }
 return result;
}

console.log(getPropValues(obj,'number'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const res = Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, rec) => {
  return [...acc, ...Object.values(rec)]
}, []).map((it) => {
  return typeof it === 'number' ? it : it.map((item) => Object.values(item))
}).reduce((acc, rec) => {
  return typeof rec === 'number' ? [...acc, rec] : [...acc, ...rec]
},[]).reduce((acc, rec) => {
  return typeof rec === 'number' ? [...acc, rec] : [...acc, ...rec]
},[])
```